# Heat capacity at constant volume Paradox

Tags: thermodynamics

Revising the Carnot cycle I have been going over my notes and have noticed something extremely interesting.

In calculating $\Delta U,\Delta W,\Delta Q$ for a specific stage in the carnot cycle, B to C

My proffessor reasoned his answer like this:

For an Adiabatic expansion, $\Delta Q = 0$

Meaning

$$\Delta U = \Delta W + \Delta Q$$

Reduces to

$$\Delta U = \Delta W $$

For some odd reason my proffessor then found $\Delta U$ by using the molar hear capacity at constant volume.

**At constant volume:**

because of $\Delta V = 0$, Implies $\Delta W = 0$, implies $\Delta U = \Delta Q$ Meaning $\Delta Q = n C_{v} \Delta T$ becomes $\Delta U = n C_{v} \Delta T$

He then plugs his numbers for this gas to obtain $0.2 * 20.8 * (300-500) = -832 J = \Delta U = \Delta W$

Why is my proffessor using the equation for $\Delta U$ at a constant volume? If the volume was constant, AND adiabatic, then $\Delta W = 0$, which from the adiabatic assumption$(\Delta U = \Delta W )$ that  implies immediately that $\Delta U = 0$ and hence a paradox

**The Further Paradox:**

If my logic is correct up until this point which i suspect it is not, I then tried to solve it correctly:

For a diatomic gas, between 500K and 300K, There are 5 quadratic degrees of freedom, from the equipartition principle each Quadratic degree of freedom impart $$\frac{1}{2}KT $$ energy per molecule

The change in the total energy for the gas of n moles is therefore

$$[\frac{5}{2}K\Delta T] * N_{a}n = -831J$$

The correct method gives basically the same result, why is it the same given the above method is wrong???

Comment: For an ideal gas, the molar internal energy u=U/n is a function only of temperature u(T) (and not volume or pressure). So, $$du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial u}{\partial  v}dv=\frac{du}{dT}dT=C_vdT$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. The answer is that the Carnot cycle works for an ideal gas, and for an ideal gas it is always true that:

$$\Delta U = c_v n \Delta T $$

Yes, even if the process is not happening at constant volume. A simple way to show it:

Consider a process at constant pressure for an ideal gas. Then:

$$dU=c_pndT-pdV=c_pndT-nRdT=nc_vdT$$

Where I've used the Mayer relation $R=c_p-c_v$. For a process at constant volume, the equation obviously holds as well.

Comment: Isn't this circular reasoning?  in deriving the mayer relation  in lectures we assumed these equations are true always to begin with [Didn't realise at the time during lecture, was confused why they were equated when they are related at different constant states]

Comment: You can also derive the internal energy expression for a gas using, for example, Gibbs thermodynamics or even statistical mechanics. This was a simple way of showing it.